# Question about oblique co-ordinate system

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

**Definitions:**

Let the following figure show an oblique $2$ dimensional co-ordinate system,

[image]

where $O$ is the origin and the parallelogram $OQRP$ is called the fundamental parallelogram. Rest of the infinite parallelograms ( those with sides parallel to $OQ$ and $OP$ ) formed are said to be based on parallelogram $OQRP$. Two points $A$ and $B$  are called **equivalent** if they are inside ( or on the boundary ) of two different parallelograms based on $OQRP$, and when the first parallelogram is made to coincide with the second ( the first parallelogram is moved along lines parallel to $OQ$ and $OP$  ), the two points coincide, for example in the figure the two red points are equivalent. Also the points of intersection in the figure above are called **lattice points**.

**Question:**

Let $R_{O}$ be a parallelogram containing the origin $O$ ( not necessarily a parallelogram based on $OQRP$ ). And let us denote $R_{P}$ to be a parallelogram congruent to $R_O$ and similarly situated about lattice point $P$. What I have to prove is that *iff* $R_{O}$ does not contain two equivalent points inside it, then *none* of the parallelograms $R_{P}^*$ coincide ( $R_P^*$ denotes the set of parallelograms around all lattice points ).

**What I tried:**

Just using the fact that a parallelogram is a convex figure, I was able to prove that if $R_{O}$ contains two equivalent points inside of it, the parallelograms $R_P^*$ will coincide. But I am unable to prove the reverse direction, that is if $R_P^*$ overlap then each of them has two equivalent points inside of them.

PS: The above is one of theorems related to Minkowski's theorems regarding [Farey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) series given in the book by Hardy and Wright ( Introduction to theory of numbers ). The concerning theorem is

> If $R_O$ is a parallelogram containing the origin such that its area is equal to that of the fundamental parallelogram $OQRP$ and there are no two equivalent points ( that is the parallelograms $R_P^*$ don't overlap  ) inside $R_O$ then the parallelograms $R_P^*$ cover the $2D$ space, where the terms are defined above in Definitions.

Comment: I do not understand the tag "elemantary-number-theory" for this question.

Comment: @Peter this was a sub-theorem under Minkowski theorems concerning Farey series in the book by Hardy an Wright. Should I remove the tag ?

Comment: I would suggest to mention this theorem. It might help to solve the problem.

Comment: @Peter I have added the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof does not make use of the fact that we are talking about a parallelogram.
Let the co-ordinates of point $Q$ and $P$ in the figure in the question be, $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ respectively. Then two points $(x,y)$ and $(x^{'},y^{'})$ are equivalent if

$$x-x^{'}=ma+nc \;...(1)$$
$$y-y^{'}=mb+nd \; ...(2)$$

for some integers $m$ and $n$. Also a lattice point $(l_x,l_y)$ can be written as

$$l_x=ma+nc \; ...(3)$$
$$l_y=mb+nd \; ...(4)$$
for some integer $m$ and $n$.
 Let us take two lattice points $A$ and $A^{'}$ and assume that the corresponding two parallelograms $R_A$ and $R_{A^{'}}$ overlap. Let $B$ be a point in this overlapping region. If we move the parallelogram $A^{'}$ along lines parallel to $OP$ and $OQ$ to coincide with parallelogram $A$ the point $B$ coincides with a point $B^{'}$ in $R_A$ such that $B$ and $B^{'}$ satisfy condition $(1)$ and $(2)$ ( as both lattice points $A$ and $A^{'}$ satisfy condition $(3)$ and $(4)$ ), thus being equivalent points inside $R_A$.